# Is my example on De Morgan's law correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wanted to create an example on De Morgan's law
$$(A\cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$$

And I thought of this: $A$ is the set of even numbers; $B$ is the set of numbers multiple of $5$.

Then $A\cup B$ is the set of even numbers multiple of $5 = \{10, 20, 30, ...\}$.

Now, $A^c$ is the set of odd numbers; $B^c$ is the set of numbers not multiple of $5$, hence $A^c \cup B^c$ is the set of numbers that are odd and not multiple of $5$.

At this point the set $(A\cap B)^c$ is the complementary of the numbers that are even and multiple of $5$, hence it's the set of numbers that are odd and not multiple of $5$.

Am I correct?

I know it's a silly question and example, but we are here to learn.

Comment: You have the meanings of $\cup$ and $\cap$ confused.  If $A$ is the set of even (*natural*) numbers and $B$ is the set of (*natural numbers who are*) multiples of five... you should have had $A\cup B$ are the set of numbers who are either even **or** multiples of five (*or both*) and would have been $\{2,4,5,6,8,10,12,14,15,16,\dots\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh gosh, you're right!! So ashamed... Thank you!!